# mySQL command line works but ODBC and workbench do not

Tags: mysql, database, odbc, driver

I am trying to test a connection to a mySQL database running on a remote linux server. I am running Windows 7 and have mySQL installed on my machine as well as the 32-bit ODBC driver.  I can connect from the DOS command prompt with no problems. But I cannot connect using mySQL workbench or with ODBC (from MS Access).

In MySQL workbench my error is:
Your connection attempt failed for user 'username' from your host to server at 'x.x.x.x:x': Unknown MySQL server host 'x.x.x.x' (0)

In MS Acess (ODBC driver) my error is:
Connection faile:[HY000][MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (10061)

I've searched stackoverflow extensively and I found lots of people who can't get ANY connection to work. But I know I can log in from my computer. Could it be something other than ports?

Comment: Also, I would add that I can connect to a db running on my localhost using the ODBC driver in MS Access. It is something about the remote connection, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Woops. It looks like the solution was to delete and recreate the connection in workbench and the file DSN from scratch and then (miraculously) it started working. I'm not sure what the cause of this error was but it is now solved. I am a new user so I can't mark this as answered yet. Nothing to see here, move along.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using correct ip address in MySQL workbench to connect to your mysql database